# For Loop for poLCA package(R) to run multiple class models

Tags: r, for-loop

I am trying to select which LCA model (R package=`poLCA`) fits my data best, based on different numbers of latent classes `nclass`.

I want to use a for loop to run the model for 1:5 latent classes, and generate a table with `G2`,`AIC` & `BIC` values for each model.

```
## Generating a table of G2,AIC & BIC for different no of LCA classes (1:5) for 6 variables. 

library(poLCA)
as.data.frame(mod_sum_v6)
for(i in 1:5){
    lca_v6<- poLCA(cbind(A,B,C,D,E,F) ~ 1, 
    maxiter=50000,nclass=i,
    nrep=1, data=data)
    mod_sum_v6[i]<-c(lca_v6$Chisq,lca_v6$resid.df,lca_v6$Gsq,lca_v6$aic,lca_v6$bic)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found this code online, It runs a sequence of models with two to ten groups. With nrep=10 it runs every model 10 times and keeps the model with the lowest BIC.

```
f<-with(mydata, cbind(F29_a,F29_b,F29_c,F27_a,F27_b,F27_e,F09_a, F09_b, F09_c)~1) #

max_II <- -100000
min_bic <- 100000
for(i in 2:10){
lc <- poLCA(f, mydata, nclass=i, maxiter=3000, 
          tol=1e-5, na.rm=FALSE,  
          nrep=10, verbose=TRUE, calc.se=TRUE)
  if(lc$bic < min_bic){
  min_bic <- lc$bic
LCA_best_model<-lc
}
}       
LCA_best_model
```